# How to return id after insert from updated (created from trigger) table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am creating an insert query to a table (t1 -Which creates the returning id by increment) which adds the same row to another table (t2) by a trigger and creates a new id. How do I get this new ID?

I tried the following approach but it returns null (I think the row in table t2 is not available yet to perform join on).

In t2 I have an identifier 'type' which detects the type of row through trigger

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
WITH inserted AS (
                INSERT INTO t1 (entity_name, entity_type, entity_country)
            VALUES
                ('sss', 'list', 'a',)
            RETURNING id, entity_country

    )

select id, entity_reference_id, entity_country, t2.entity_id from inserted
    join t2 on t1.id = t2.entity_reference_id
where t2.type LIKE '%manual%'
```

This returns me null, However I want it to return me new t2.entity_id

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION view_t2_id() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW."type" LIKE '%manual%') THEN
        RETURN NEW."entity_id";
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Wrong "type"="%"', NEW."type";
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER view_t2_id_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON t2
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE view_t2_id();
```